# Make nginx treat another extension as mp4

Tags: nginx

I have converted an animated gif `animated.gif` to an mp4 `animated.mp4`.I then rename `animated.mp4`  to `animated.gifv`. How can i tell nginx to treat `.gifv` files as mp4,

Here is my attempt thus far

```
location ~* \.(mp4|gifv)$ {
     mp4;
     mp4_buffer_size 4M;
     mp4_max_buffer_size 10M;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to set the mime type:

```
location ~* \.(mp4|gifv)$ {
    default_type video/mp4;

    mp4;
    mp4_buffer_size 4M;
    mp4_max_buffer_size 10M;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) for more.